# extract year and month from character date field R

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a column in my large data set called `Date`. How do I extract both the year and month from it? I would like to create a column `Month` where the month goes from `1-12` and `year` where the year goes from the first year in my data set to the last year in my data set.

Thanks.

```
> typeof(data$Date)
[1] "character

> head(data$Date)
[1] "2/06/2020 11:23"  "12/06/2020 7:56"  "12/06/2020 7:56"  "29/06/2020 16:54" "3/06/2020 15:09"  "25/06/2020 17:11"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` and `lubridate` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy_hm(Date), 
         month = month(Date), 
         year = year(Date))

#                 Date month year
#1 2020-06-02 11:23:00     6 2020
#2 2020-06-12 07:56:00     6 2020
#3 2020-06-12 07:56:00     6 2020
#4 2020-06-29 16:54:00     6 2020
#5 2020-06-03 15:09:00     6 2020
#6 2020-06-25 17:11:00     6 2020
```

Base R -

```
data$Date <- as.POSIXct(data$Date, tz = 'UTC', format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
data <- transform(data, Month = format(Date, '%m'), Year = format(Date, '%Y'))
```

**data**

```
data <- structure(list(Date = c("2/06/2020 11:23", "12/06/2020 7:56", 
"12/06/2020 7:56", "29/06/2020 16:54", "3/06/2020 15:09", "25/06/2020 17:11"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```